# AES for new blank Desfire EV1

Tags: aes, rfid, mifare

I now have a new Desfire EV1 card. And I want to set PICC master key with AES encryption. How could I do that? So far I can get the session key using single DES.

Comment: I believe the default key is all 0's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One place to start might be libfreefare or its parent, nfc-tools.

http://code.google.com/p/nfc-tools/wiki/libfreefare

Comment: they only have examples for 3des encryption.

Comment: They have code for setting AES keys, though. Haven't looked too closely at it, but I assume it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to obtain the datasheet from the manufacturer [NXP](http://www.nxp.com). Debugging or reverse-engineering crypto-functionality without proper documentation is extremely hard.